# How do I cache vectorized calls that take user input in R?

Tags: r, caching, bigdata, vectorization, user-input

I am trying to calculate a field for all rows of a large dataset. The function to calculate it is from the package taxize, and uses an HTTP request to query an external site for the right ID number. It is searching by scientific name, and often there are multiple results, in which case this function asks for user input. I would like the function to cache my selection and return that ID number every time the same call is made from then on. I have tried with my own caching function and with memoizedCall() from the package R.cache but every time it hits the second entry of the same scientific name it still prompts me for user input. I feel like I am misunderstanding something basic about how vectorization works. Sorry for my ignorance but any advice is appreciated.

Here is the code I used as a custom caching function.

```
check_tsn <- function(data,tsn_list){
  print(data)
  print(tsn_list)
  if (is.null(tsn_list$data)){
    tsn_list$data = taxize::get_tsn(data)
    print('added to tsn_list')
  }
  return(tsn_list$data)
}
tsn_list <- vector(mode = "list", nrow(wanglang))
Genus.Species <- c('Tamiops swinhoei','Bos taurus','Tamiops swinhoei')
IUCN.ID <- c('21382','','21382')
species <- data.frame(Genus.Species,IUCN.ID)
species$TSN.ID = check_tsn(species$Genus.Species,tsn_list)
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Here `wanglang` is undefined.